# Fitting UIImage inside a Table Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uiimageview, storyboard

I have a table with a custom cell, which has only one `UIImageView`. I want each cell to have its own height based on an image height I will place in it. In my `heightForRow` method I have

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  FAppFormula *formula = self.formulas[indexPath.row];
  UIImage *img = [formula getFormulaImageSmallSize];

  if (img.size.height <= 100){
    return 30;
  }

  return 75;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *cellIDSmall = @"FormulaCellSmall";

   FormulaCell *cell = (FormulaCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIDSmall
                                                                   forIndexPath:indexPath];

   cell.formulaImage.image = formulaImg;

   return cell;
}
```

The cells themselves do get proper heights, however images don't get scaled appropriately. In `storyboard` cell prototype I set `UIImageView`'s mode to **Aspect Fit**, however looks like all images get scaled based on a default(?) row height, but not on the one which `heightForRowAtIndexPath` returns...

Any ideas on why it happens and how to fix it? [How it looks now img](http://imageshack.com/a/img843/6186/2beq.png)

Comment: Have you set your constraints on the image view so that it resizes with the cell?

Comment: Did you check if the image view is resized to the right frame based on the cell's height?

Comment: Adding constraints did the job, thank you @skladek!